# Is that possible to show screen inside a tmux session without attach in?

Tags: tmux

I'm running a monitor inside a tmux session, and now I want to see the status.

Surely I can `tmux attach -t monitor` and then detach.

But I'm wondering is there a convenient way to just have a look inside the session without attach&detach?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using 
`tmux ls` 
to get the session name and then
`tmux capture-pane -pt <session name>` 
to get a snapshot of whats going on inside.